# Glossaries-extra does not emphasize first occurrences

Tags: glossaries-extra

Normally, glossaries-extra is supposed to emphasize the first occurrence of a glossary entry in text. In my case it does not and I do not understand why.

The project is too large to share in its entirety, but I will try to post relevant lines of code.

```
%main.tex
\documentclass[fleqn,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[acronym,symbols,nogroupskip,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}

\RestoreAcronyms
% \glssetcategoryattribute{general}{textformat}{textit}
\loadglsentries[main]{glossaries/glo.tex}
\makenoidxglossaries




\begin{document}
    
    % BODY
    \include{content/theory}
    
    %GLOSSARIES
    \pagebreak
    \printnoidxglossary[sort=word,style=super]
    
    \pagebreak
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]

\end{document}
```

```
%glo.tex
%\newglossaryentry{linear inverse problem}{name=linear inverse problem,first={\emph{linear inverse problem}},
    description={}}
\newglossaryentry{linear inverse problem}{name=linear inverse problem,
    description={}}
```

```
%theory.tex
\section{Theoretical Framework}
    In this section the theoretical framework shall be laid out starting with the information theoretical fundamentals. First, the central \gls{linear inverse problem} is outlined, followed by the algorithm intended to solve it including the employed principles of machine learning. Finally the underlying physical model is introduced.
```

Uncommenting the `\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{textformat}{textit}` yields what you would expect: All occurances are emphasized. Without it the first one is not emphasized.
`\glsresetall{}` does not do anything either.
However, specifying any entry like this `\newglossaryentry{linear inverse problem}{name=linear inverse problem,first={\emph{linear inverse problem}}, description={}}` does emphasize the first occurrence.

Is this a bug?

Comment: That is correct, I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: thanks.........

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue using

```
\defglsentryfmt{%
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}{%
    \glsgenentryfmt%
  }{%
    % Typeset first use
    \emph{\glsgenentryfmt}%
  }%
}
```

in the preamble. I still do not know what caused it in the first place.